# How to normalize a database/dataset in Access or any other database?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, dataset

I'm trying to build an OLAP database with [this](https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results/version/2) data set about the Olympics, the problem is that datasets are in csv format and they are usually in one single table, I've imported the data in access as I was told that Access has a tool to split the data in different tables but I have not found anything related to that. This is my current table:

[image: tabla actual]

Id1 is the one created in access so it could include the duplicated data, ID is the original one in the data set.

I want to normalize the data into the following schema:

[image: schema]

I've tried to split data manually, but since there are lots of data, It's risky and prone to a lot of mistakes and errors.

Any idea on how to do this on Access or is there a better method to do it?

Comment: Not sure I'd have that particular relational structure ..

Comment: @CaiusJard I know, the thing is that OLAP structures require a similar schema to quantify the data.

Comment: working on the answer. In short create a correct database structure.  Then import data into each table separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already imported your data into access and that data still needs to be normalized you can use an access wizard under database tools - analyze table.  This wizard will help you normalize a table by splitting the original table into multiple tables.  Here is one link to get you started with the table analyzer:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/normalize-your-data-using-the-table-analyzer-8edbb763-5bab-4fbc-b62d-c17b1a40bbe2

The table analyzer will create new tables and copy the data from the original table into the new tables resulting in a structure like the following:
[image]
The table analyzer will even save the query it uses so you can reuse it later.  However if you just choose defaults the wizard will not give you appropriate names for keys and tables. Also you might want to adjust the relationship structure access chooses.  You can do all these things in the wizard once you are familiar with it.  In this case I just renamed all the tables and keys but left seasons as the top of the relationships pile.

Alternately you can Import the data one table at a time but you will have to clean it first (particularly adding primary keys) or you will have problems.  The data import wizard in access has the option to skip variables under one of the advanced tabs.
You can skip the table analyzer wizard and create the tables and write the queries to transfer the data yourself but The wizard is faster :)

Data Cleaning Commentary: Under the heading a picture is worth a thousand words it helps if you post your data and what you want.  I found the dataset online and I have a couple comments that may be helpful. ID has a one to many relationship with Country so it cannot be used as a primary key.  So let access provide primary keys.  Age has missing data so a decision will need to be made on how to handle that, I just put the problem off by converting age to a text variable.

Comment: Thanks I had some minor errors, but i fixed them, thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome.  PS each country has many IDs rather than the other way around.